# Cosmos DB not triggering

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I need some help clarifying something here. I'm have two functions as seen below

## **Function.cs**

```
   [Function("TestServiceBus")]
   public async Task ServiceBusReceivedMessageFunction(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("key-vault-test-queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
   {
       _logger.LogInformation($"Message ID: {message.MessageId}");
       _logger.LogInformation($"Message Body: {message.Body}");
       _logger.LogInformation($"Message Content-Type: {message.ContentType}");

       SetSecretsValues();

       await CosmoDBRead();
       //await CreateContainerCosmoDB();
       await UpdateCosmosDBItem(message.Body.ToString());
   }

   [Function("CosmosFunctionTrigger")]
   public void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
       databaseName: "ToDoList",
       containerName: "Items_v2",
       Connection = "ConnectionStrings",
       LeaseContainerName = "leases",
       CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input)
   {
       if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
           _logger.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].id);
       }
   }
```

Within UpdateCosmosDBItem method I update the item with the Id and partition key as seen below

```
   private async Task UpdateCosmosDBItem(string message)
   {
       CosmosClient cosmoClient = new CosmosClient(
           accountEndpoint: this._endpointUri,
           new DefaultAzureCredential()
       );

       Database database = cosmoClient.GetDatabase("ToDoList");
       Container container = database.GetContainer("Items_v2");

       ToDoItem readItem = await container.ReadItemAsync<ToDoItem>(
           id: "1234",
           partitionKey: new PartitionKey("1234")
       );

       readItem.Description = message;

       await container.UpsertItemAsync<ToDoItem>(readItem);

       _logger.LogInformation("Item has been updated");
   }
```

How I understand it, it should trigger the CosmoDBTrigger function because it detected a change. It does not trigger that function. What am I not understanding here?

## Solution

A solution has been found. The reason that the cosmosDB wasn't triggering was because the connectionString was not in the configurations of the function in Azure portal. Which is strange because I remember adding it. It could be that I have misspelled it and didn't catch the mistake.

Comment: The logic looks fine. Is there any invocation log that you see for the cosmosdbtrigger function? Is it possible the connection the cosmos fails in the background?

Comment: It shouldn't because I can make a manual change in cosmosdb and it detects those changes with no issue. I can check the logs to see if it failed.

Comment: Can you share your host.json?

Comment: Correction. I have tried manually editing the table and the cosmos db trigger is not triggering anymore. No errors or other information is shown besides that it is still waiting for function to be triggered

Comment: @Pavan This is what it looks like 
{
   "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionAppDemo1": "Information",
      "Host.Triggers.CosmosDB": "Trace"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @DonDavid12 - please be sure to edit your question, to provide details such as your host.json, especially since it is formatted text (hard to read in comments)

Comment: Make sure you have logs enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-configure-cosmos-db-trigger#enabling-trigger-specific-logs, verify that none of the known scenarios is happening https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#some-changes-are-missing-in-your-trigger, make sure your Function is a actually running and **please** do not create **CosmosClient** in `UpdateCosmosDBItem` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#azure-cosmos-db-clients

Comment: FYI solutions don't belong as edits to the question. Also, since this was a corrected misspelling/error, the question should be closed/deleted.

Answer (score -1):

> Cosmos DB not triggering

I have created servicebus trigger function and cosmosdb trigger function with runtime stack dotnet using visual studio.
I made some changes in your code. check below:

**Servicebus function:**

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp13334
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task ServiceBusReceivedMessageFunction(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("firstqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Message ID: {message.MessageId}");
            logger.LogInformation($"Message Body: {message.Body}");
            logger.LogInformation($"Message Content-Type: {message.ContentType}"
        }
    }
}
```

I have created the updatefunction with cosmosclient and call that function in cosmosdb trigger function and also I could not gave the id and partitionkey in code. I was directly give in the cosmosdb data explorer.
when I made any changes in container items and updated it would be triggered the function in Local.

- I have called the update function in the cosmosdb trigger function to update the items in container. But in the above update function is not calling inside the cosmosdb trigger function. for that when any changes happened in container cosmosdb function got triggered.

**Cosmosdb function:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp13334
{
    public static class Function
    {
        [FunctionName("Function")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "ToDoList1",
            containerName: "Items_v2",
            Connection = "cosmoscon",
            LeaseContainerName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].id);

                foreach (var item in input)
                {
                    await UpdateFunction.UpdateCosmosDBItemAsync(item.Description, log);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Customize the model with your own desired properties
    public class ToDoItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update function:**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp13334
{
    public static class UpdateFunction
    {
        private static readonly string _endpointUri = "you-cosmos URI";
        private static readonly string _databaseName = "ToDoList";
        private static readonly string _containerName = "Items_v2";
        private static readonly string _primaryKey = "your-cosmosdb-primarykey"; // Add your Cosmos DB primary key
        public static async Task UpdateCosmosDBItemAsync(string message, ILogger log)
        {
            var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(
                _endpointUri,
                _primaryKey); // Use the Cosmos DB primary key for authentication

            var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
            var container = database.GetContainer(_containerName);
           

            // Implement your update logic here
            // For demonstration, let's just log the message
            log.LogInformation($"Updating Cosmos DB item with message: {message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "cosmoscon": "your-cosmosdb-conn-string",
    "ServiceBusConnection": "your-servicebus conn-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

**Host.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to receive messages from servicebus queue and cosmosdb function got triggered after make any changes and updated in Items. check below:

**Output:**
[image]

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5530 Commit hash: N/A +c8883e7f3c06e2b424fbac033806c19d8d91418c (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.5.21962

[2024-02-25T07:42:25.556Z] Found C:\Users\v-ppesala\source\repos\FunctionApp13334\FunctionApp13334.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        Function: cosmosDBTrigger

        Function1: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-25T07:42:35.920Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000D8932B9B'.
[2024-02-25T07:43:22.508Z] Executing 'Function' (Reason='New changes on container Items_v2 at 2024-02-25T07:43:22.3865888Z', Id=2eede4af-b168-4493-8766-68b89fe56414)
[2024-02-25T07:43:22.567Z] Documents modified 1
[2024-02-25T07:43:22.572Z] First document Id 89842948099878
[2024-02-25T07:43:22.620Z] Updating Cosmos DB item with message:
[2024-02-25T07:43:22.707Z] Executed 'Function' (Succeeded, Id=2eede4af-b168-4493-8766-68b89fe56414, Duration=279ms)
[2024-02-25T07:43:29.493Z] Executing 'Function' (Reason='New changes on container Items_v2 at 2024-02-25T07:43:29.4932896Z', Id=5a4e62a5-8a2d-4d0d-9beb-5e75c69f79e6)
[2024-02-25T07:43:29.498Z] Documents modified 1
[2024-02-25T07:43:29.502Z] First document Id 898429499878
[2024-02-25T07:43:29.543Z] Updating Cosmos DB item with message:
[2024-02-25T07:43:29.548Z] Executed 'Function' (Succeeded, Id=5a4e62a5-8a2d-4d0d-9beb-5e75c69f79e6, Duration=55ms)
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.618Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=b921fa13-b96a-4579-a230-65fda203eeb8)
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.657Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 1274a97776b246a59c8e47caf82ada9e, SequenceNumber: 4, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-02-25T07:43:57.6670000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-02-25T07:44:57.6820000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.664Z] Message ID: 1274a97776b246a59c8e47caf82ada9e
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.676Z] Message Body: hello pavan
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.680Z] Message Content-Type:
[2024-02-25T07:43:57.684Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=b921fa13-b96a-4579-a230-65fda203eeb8, Duration=162ms)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer any question; rather, it's a huge amount of code, along with "I made some changes." You don't need to rewrite someone's code, but you *do* need to explain exactly what you changed, and why/how this fixes their problem (along with explaining what their problem actually is). The OP shouldn't have to study what you wrote to figure things out.

Comment: Updated the solution with clear explanation.

Comment: Your edit doesn't correct the problem: It says nothing about the OP's issue, nor does it explain how your solution is in any way different. This isn't about publishing some code that you made. This is about addressing the OP's issues.

Comment: I have updated the solution with the changes which I made in the code.